# Selenium Testing: Programming a more robust test

Tags: java, selenium

I am attempting to automate a task involving a JavaServer Page using the Selenium Webdriver. I have built a test that works about 90% of the time, meaning that the Webdriver makes it through all the tasks without any errors. During the test the browser executes the actions below:

- opens a page
- clicks on a link and switches windows
- closes the original window
- logs into a system
- switches frames
- clicks a link
- fills out a form
- submits the form
- ...more similar tasks

Unfortunatly, some of the time the Webdriver will randomly fail on one of the steps. This is because it could not find something, for example 'no frame found', 'unable to find element with link text...' and other similar errors. I am not sure why this happens sometimes and it appears to happen randomly at different stages in the test. I searched around for a solution and the best I could do was slow down the Webdriver with thread.sleep at various stages in the program. This seems like a very haphazard way to solve the problem to me and I am not even sure the problem is that the driver is moving too quickly. Even if I slow it down half a second I still sometimes get errors. I am a new user of Selenium and I do not know if this is usually a problem. Does anyone have a better way to address this problem? Am I overlooking something simple?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did the same initially using thread sleep to develop my scripts. However, even though the scripts work while development, but it will be **unrealiable on a production run** as it fail inconsistently --**which adds to the frustration**. This is because thread sleep utilizes fixed waiting time and if elements do not get attached in time, it will fail the tests. **singe31** has given a valid solution. Another solution would be by using **fluentWait**:

```
public void fluentWait(final By by)
{
    FluentWait<WebDriver> wait = new FluentWait<WebDriver>(driver)
               .withTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
               .pollingEvery(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
               .ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class);

           WebElement foo = wait.until(new Function<WebDriver, WebElement>() {
             public WebElement apply(WebDriver driver) {
               return driver.findElement(by);
             }
           });
}
```

Here, the Selenium Webdriver will wait for at least 60 seconds to find an element until it throws of an TimeOutException. Otherwise, it will poll the DOM to find the element every 5 seconds and if the element is not found "NoSuchElementException" exception will be ignored.

Another problem which you are bound to face is, StaleStateReference or NoSuchElementException. You can check [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24635075/2319531) for solving that issue.

Hope it helps.

Comment: What if element wait is not a concern. The element is loaded, but sometimes Selenium clicks it and sometimes it doesn't. Due to which the test after the click (based on it) fails randomly.

Answer (score 1):

It's a common issue, instead of using `Thread.sleep(duration)` you should better create some utility method like

```
public WebElement waitForElementPresent(By by, int timeout) {

    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, timeout);
    WebElement element = null;
    try {
        element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(by));
    } catch (TimeoutException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return element;
}
```

This way if the element is already there you won't wait, and if it's loading it will wait until it finds it or until the timeout is triggered